# Can this printing be done in Flash/Java?

Tags: java, flash, printing

I would like to know if the following can be done in flash/Java:

I have an ASP.NET web site from which I need to be able to print/send a specific set of instructions to a code-bar printer. Since this can't be done from javascript, I thought maybe a client side app/plugin (Flash, Java) could do it.

Do any of you know if this can be done? where can I find how to do it?

many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to print in Java, for a website you could develop a Java applet. There is an official [Java website available about printing](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/printing/) which includes API documentation and tutorials. The only catch is because of the Java security model the applet needs to be signed.
Here is another [link from Java about signing applets](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html). Note that you are able to create your own signature (as opposed to having one from a certificate authority), it will just pop up a warning when the applet loads, which may be ok depending on the audience of your website.